# $M\to S^{-1}M$ is an isomorphism iff for all $W$ with $S^{-1}W=0$ all maps $W\to M$ are zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, let $S\subset R$ be multiplicative and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Is the following true?

> The localization map $M\to S^{-1}M$ is an isomorphism if and only if for all $R$-modules $W$ such that $S^{-1}W=0$, all maps $W\to M$ are zero.

The direction $\Rightarrow$ is easy: it follows from functoriality of localization. But I can't prove or disprove $\Leftarrow$. Note that the condition $S^{-1}W=0$ implies that all elements of $W$ are annihilated by some element of $S$.

Answer (score 2):

I think $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ (so $R = M = \mathbb{Z}$ and $S = \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$) provides a counterexample.  Given an abelian group $W$, then $S^{-1} W = 0$ iff $W$ is torsion, i.e., every element has finite order.  Since $0$ is only element of $\mathbb{Z}$ of finite order, given a homomorphism $W \to \mathbb{Z}$, then every element must map to $0$.  Thus the hypothesis on the righthand side is satisfied, but the localization map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is not an isomorphism.

However, one can show the localization map is injective given the hypothesis on the righthand side.  Letting $\varphi: M \to S^{-1} M$ be the localization map, take $W = \ker(\varphi)$.  Given $m \in \ker(\varphi)$, then $\frac{ms}{s} = \frac{0}{s}$, so there exists $t \in S$ such that
$$
0 = t(ms^2 - 0\cdot s) = s^2 t m \, .
$$
Thus $S^{-1}W = 0$.  By the hypothesis, then the inclusion map $\ker(\varphi) \hookrightarrow M$ must be the zero map, so $\ker(\varphi) = 0$.

Comment: I don't get the part where you prove that $S^{-1}W=0$. (For instance, what is that $s$?) If $m\in\ker\varphi$ then $\frac m1=\frac 01$, that's all. (Do you assume somehow that $R$ has no unit? But then how define the canonical map $M\to S^{-1}M$?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think that there should be a correct result close to what I formulated that keeps the condition that $M\to S^{-1}M$ is an isomorphism, but I can't figure out what it is. Could you help me?

Comment: @user26857 The OP doesn't seem to assume $1 \in S$, in which case one can define $M \to S^{-1} M$ by choosing any $s \in S$ and sending $m \mapsto \frac{ms}{s}$.  Maybe  assuming $1 \in S$ (a very mild assumption) would have made the proof a bit cleaner.

Comment: @user46225 I'll think some more about it and see if I come up with anything.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I should have said so but I am assuming that $1\in S$, yes.